# TeamCity checkbox parameter

Tags: command-line, teamcity-8.0

I am looking to implement a flag to make sure no one tiggers a job by mistake.
I have added a parameter which prompts before the the job is triggerd.

An command line build step is created with the following script:

```
IF %ConfirmationCheck% == "false"  exit 1;
```

No matter what setting the confirmation box has, it always starts the rest of the steps.

Anyone an idea?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I'm using powershell to do the same thing

```
if ("%ConfirmPrompt%" -eq "false")
{
    Write-Host "Error: Confirmation checkbox was not checked"
    exit 1
}
```

Make sure that you edit the parameter and set the un/checked value, mine are set to false/true respectively.